# Flex 3 Website: Google Webmaster Tools Lists zero keywords

Tags: apache-flex, keyword, google-search-console

I've got a Flex 3 website. Unfortunately, Google Webmaster Tools lists zero keywords for my site. My site's been up for about a month. I submitted a sitemap. I've put a description and keywords metatags in the HTML wrapper.

Any advise on what else I should do? Does anyone have a Flex 3 site for which Google Webmaster Tools lists keywords?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just checked and it seems that google ignores (or gives very low weight to) html meta keywords, like [robertc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8655/robertc) and [www.Flextras.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133840/www-flextras-com) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509968/flex-3-website-google-webmaster-tools-lists-zero-keywords/4510040#4510040).

But since Google (like any other crawler I've heard of) have a very hard time reading non-text content (well, they're doing some analysis of images, and also read some specific Flash containers for text), they *do* pay attention to the ALT attribute of the image or object tags.  Of course, this isn't supposed to be a list of keywords, it should be a human-readable description of the object.

Another place that Google does read is the HTML description meta-tag [see here](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79812)

Comment: Hi Javier, Thank you for the message. I've got the filepaths for my images stored in a database and I load the images dynamically. Is there an ALT equivalent for Flex? And if there is would it make a difference adding the tag. As I understand it, Google's crawler doesn't access anything that's pulled from the database. I have included an HTML description meta-tag. If you have any suggestions on how to get my site in front of more people, I'd love to hear it. Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: In your case, the images loaded by Flash aren't seen by google, since that's only created by a program executing in the browser.  Google only sees your HTML wrapper.  there you can both include the metatags with descriptions of your site, and also an ALT on the object tag that pulls your flash app.  In the end, a passable solution is to create a simplistic HTML site with the same content, and make that only visible to non-flash browsers (that would include the googlebot); but that would only help if an URL that goes directly to some content works in both the flash and html versions.

Comment: Hi Javier, Thank you for the suggestions. Feliz Navidad

Answer (score 1):

If Search engine placement is important to you, you may want to reconsider using the Flex / Flash as the basis of your site.  As best we know, Google and other search engines have a hard time crawling Flash based content.

Flash is great for advanced animation and video, and for applications functionality.  But not for delivering content that needs to be searched.

Comment: all true, but the question mentions that the HTML wrapper contains both description and keywords.

Comment: @Javier but does the HTML contain any actual content?  Meta tags are largely ignored for indexing.

Comment: Hi Flextras.com, Thank you for the message. My site's already built, so I can't re-do it. (Also, I wouldn't be able to do it using another technology). In any event, do your Flex sites have keywords listed when you look in Google Webmaster Tools?

Comment: @javier My understanding was the same as @robertc here.  Description / keywords are ignored or used only in elation to the page content.  As far as a search engine is concerned, it sounds like the content is empty.  @Laxmidi Idon't have any public Flex site to test against. In my experience, Flex is most commonly used for building Applications which have no need for search.  I usually explain this by asking people if they want to search Word or do you want to search their Word Documents?